# Obtain Position of value for Event

Tags: vba, excel, event-handling

Hello I been trying to find the best way to do this and unfortunately the steps Ive taken hasnt given me the results I was hoping for. I would like to create an event that highlights a cell but only if its located on a specific range. Now the tricky part is that the range can change depending on the information been displayed with a button I created. For example I have A1,A2 and after pressing the button the range can change to A1..A5. I dont want the cell A6 for example to get highlighted since there is no information here or the information there does not matter. Here is what I have done so far but currently receiving An application defined or object defined error on the INSTR function inside the loop. I have created the following in a class for this event:

```
Private Sub m_wb_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Dim i As Integer
Dim startpos As Integer
Dim Endpos As Integer
For i = 0 To 50
    If (InStr(m_wb.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 5).Value, "multiplier") > 0) Then startpos = i
    If (InStr(m_wb.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 5).Value, "total") > 0) Then Endpos = i
Next i
If Sh.name = "Sheet1" And (Target.Column = 7 Or Target.Column = 2 Or Target.Column = 3) And Not IsEmpty(m_wb.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(3, 1).Value) And Target.Row > startpos - 1 and Target.Row < Endpos Then Target.Interior.Color = vbYellow
End Sub
```

Comment: The row value cannot be `0` and hence you are getting that error

Comment: @SiddharthRout Awesome that was easy thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The row value cannot be `0` and hence you are getting that error" - @SiddharthRout